# Null Pointer Exception when calling a function from another class android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

there are two activity class A & B. B has on function, and i tried to call a B's function from the class A. But it shows NULL Pointer Exception Error. i searched in Stack over flow but i didn't get exact solution. can anyone Please help.

Class A

```
try
{
    String name="vijay";
    Sends obj=new Sends();
    obj.fun(name);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(GoodActivity.this, e.toString()+"good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Class B

```
public void fun(String s)
{
    Toast.makeText(Sends.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: i posted the code @Takendarkk

Comment: Please format your code so that it is actually readable. In which line did you get the NPE?

Comment: when calling the function obj.fun(name) @Henry

Comment: Are you sure? `obj.fun(name)` can only throw a NPE if `obj` is null. However, `obj` was set to a new object just the line before ...

Comment: yes sure obj.fun(name only)...